# AddEventListener by class on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I would like to trigger an event when an element with a given class is clicked in **pure JS**. Here is a sample of my dom:

```
<div id="editor">
    <div class="bold">bla bla</div>
    <div class="bold">bla bla</div>
</div>
```

The element `<div class="bold">bla bla</div>` are dynamically added.

I already tried:

```
let editor = document.getElementById('editor');
Array.prototype.filter.call( editor.getElementsByClassName('bold') , function (prismCode) {
    ...
});
```

None works with dynamics elements.

and:

```
document.getElementById('editor').querySelectorAll(".bold").forEach(() => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Can you listen for the click on the static parent element and then check the target element after it propagates?

Comment: @DBS not a clean solution, with jQuery, I did `$('#editor').on('click', '.bold', function() {` so i should be possible in Vanilla JS

Comment: Do you use `createElement`?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner the element is added by a library, I don't how it works inside

Comment: If so, maybe event delegation (pure JS) is the only way.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner event delegation does not work, because in my application, this is nested elements, I have to test every parents, that's payfull

Comment: @MisterJojo What ?!?!?

Comment: Get it, that's a type. I updated the question

Comment: "event delegation does not work..." - The answer you've accepted uses event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

use event delegation ?

```js
document.querySelector('#editor').addEventListener('click', foo)

function foo(event)
  {
  if (!event.target.matches('.bold')) return // case of outer space clicks
  
  console.clear()
  console.log( event.target.textContent )
  }
```

sample code

```js
const
  btAdd     = document.querySelector('#bt-add')
, editorDiv = document.querySelector('#editor')

editorDiv.onclick = e => 
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('.bold')) return
  
  console.clear()
  console.log( e.target.textContent )
  }


// addin bla blabla elements...
var blablaCounter = 2

btAdd.onclick = _ => 
  {
  let newBlaBla = document.createElement('div')
  newBlaBla.className   = 'bold'
  newBlaBla.textContent = `bla bla ${++blablaCounter}`
  editorDiv.appendChild( newBlaBla )
  }
```

```css
.bold 
  {
  font-size : .7em;
  border    : 1px solid blue;
  padding   : .5em;
  margin    : .3em;
  cursor    : pointer
  }
.bold:hover
  {
  background : yellow;
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-add"> add simulator </button>

<div id="editor">
    <div class="bold">bla bla 1</div>
    <div class="bold">bla bla 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like following ?

```js
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
var targetClass = editor.querySelectorAll(".bold");
addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("class", "bold");
    newDiv.innerText = "bla bla";
    editor.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(`clicked`)
    });

})

targetClass.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(`clicked `)
    });
})
```

```html
<div id="editor">
        <div class="bold">bla bla</div>
        <div class="bold">bla bla</div>
 </div>
 <button id="add">Add Element </button>
```

Comment: Does not work on dynamicaly created elements

Comment: It works because you create the element with createElement, but does not works if you use innerHtml = "..."

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party,
but If you want to explicitly attach an event on a dynamically created element, you need to loop through all elements and then add as shown below:

```
function attachEventOnList() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll("#editor .bold");
  list.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
      console.log("event:: ", evt);
    });
  });
}
```

For working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/green-monad-vcop7?file=/src/index.js