# currentPage.addEventListener("animationend"), bug after some slides it is executed twice

Tags: javascript

I'll show you the code but let me explain.
If i click on an arrow (see screen 1), the updateArrows function is called and at the end, next() is called for update the steps.
Everything is working perfectly, if I click on the down arrow until step 4, no problem. On the screen 1 you can see the result of the console.log(nextPage) which is in the next() function.

After that, if i click on the top arrow 2 times (if i go back to the step 2 then), at the step 3, its all good, at the step 2, the      currentPage.addEventListener("animationend",function (e) { }) is executed twice, on the console you can see the 2 last nextPage values 2 times, one time with the good value (2) and one time with the value 4 (see screen 2).

I think the problem come from a double listening of the animationend event, but at first I can't explain why the problem does not occur before ?

Screen 1 :
[image]

Screen 2 :
[image]

Code :

```
const changeStep = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
const currentPaginate = document.querySelector(".pagination span.active");
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
let isAnimating = false;

for (let arrow of arrows) arrow.addEventListener("click", updateArrows);

for (let step of changeStep) step.addEventListener("click", next);

function updateArrows(e, currentStep = null) {
    if (isAnimating) return false;
    let arrow = null;
    e.target ? (arrow = e.target) : (arrow = e);
    let nextStep;
    if (currentStep == null) {
        currentStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
        if (arrow.classList.contains("arrow-bottom")) {
            nextStep = currentStep.nextElementSibling;
        } else {
            nextStep = currentStep.previousElementSibling;
        }
    } else {
        nextStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
    }
    if (!arrow.classList.contains("impossible")) {
        if (nextStep.dataset.id != 1 && nextStep.dataset.id != 4) {
            arrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                if (arrow.classList.contains("impossible")) {
                    arrow.classList.remove("impossible");
                }
            });
        } else if (nextStep.dataset.id == 4) {
            if (arrow.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("impossible"))
                arrow.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("impossible");
            arrow.classList.add("impossible");
        } else if (nextStep.dataset.id == 1) {
            if (arrow.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("impossible"))
                arrow.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("impossible");
            arrow.classList.add("impossible");
        }
        if (e.target != undefined) next(nextStep);
    }
}

function next(e) {
    if (isAnimating) {
        return false;
    }
    isAnimating = true;
    let step = null;
    const currentPage = document.querySelector(".page.current");
    e.target ? (step = e.target) : (step = e);

    if (!step.classList.contains("current")) {
        const currentStep = document.querySelector(".step.current");
        const nextStep = step.dataset.id;
        const nextPage = document.querySelector('[data-id="' + nextStep + '"]');
        currentStep.classList.remove("current");
        step.classList.add("current");
        currentPaginate.textContent = "0" + nextStep;
        let arrow;
        if (currentStep.dataset.id < nextStep) {
            arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow-bottom");
        } else {
            arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow-top");
        }
        currentPage.addEventListener(
            "animationend",
            function (e) {
                e = window.event || e;
                if (this === e.target) {
                    currentPage.classList.remove("current", "moveToBottomFade");
                    nextPage.classList.add("current");
                    console.log(nextPage);
                    isAnimating = false;
                }
            },
            true
        );
        currentPage.classList.add("moveToBottomFade");
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use your events by delegation? this allows centralized management, and it also avoids duplicating EventListeners

Comment: Do you have an exemple please ? I put the animationend listener in the next function because I needed the updated values inside

Comment: your function `updateArrows(e, currentStep = null)` is not valid, the event handler use only  event  as argument, and no other

Comment: it's best to use event handlers globally, not add and remove them contextually. You can still use flags to describe different contexts

Comment: there are already here a certain number of questions / answers on the management of event delegation. One of mine...-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819677/addeventlistener-by-class-on-dynamically-created-element/68820584#68820584

Comment: I think it's not the same problem, for that i made : if (this === e.target)

Comment: For the update arrows, its because the function was called differently a few hours earlier, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... But if someone can explain me why, it would be perfect.
It seems like my removeEventlistener doesn't work because i just added a once:true to my listener, and now it works perfectly !
Code :

```
    currentPage.addEventListener(
        "animationend",
        function (e) {
            //if(isAnimating === true)
            e = window.event || e;
            if (this === e.target) {
                currentPage.removeEventListener("animationend", e);
                currentPage.classList.remove(
                    "current",
                    "moveToBottomFade"
                );
                nextPage.classList.add("current");
                isAnimating = false;
            }
        },
        { once: true }
    );
    currentPage.classList.add("moveToBottomFade");
```